# How to convert long date format (dddd, MMM d, yyyy) into date in UFT?

Tags: vba, date, hp-uft

I'm still new at UFT, but I've come across a problem that I haven't been able to figure out. I'm testing the web based portion of our application right now, and there's dates in all kinds of formats (dd/mm/yyyy, MMM d, YYYY, MMM yyyy)

The one I can't seem to convert to a date is (dddd, MMM d, yyyy).
I found this: ' In addition, a long date format is not recognized if it also contains the day-of-the-week string.' on the CDate function page for ADM help.

So I guess my question is, how do I handle this format? Do I remove the first word in the string? Is there another way to do this? - Thanks all for any help